# How to find the shear stress and bending moments of uninform distributed load

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, moment

I can't for the life of me find a way to solve this.

Given is the length of a T girder, which is fixed at one and on rolled support on the other side

Now in the exercises given during class there would be a point load and a evenly distributed one, so making the shear force diagram is easy, calculate Ma and then subtract the point load once you reach it, and for the distributed load divide its force by the length of impact and subtract this for every meter and connect the dots.

For bending moments I integrate the shear force by calculating the area under the curve. Worked fine but

On the exam there where a point load, an even distributed load and an uneven distributed load on top of the distributed one. Problem is I can't use the area method since the shear force is a curve when uneven distributed. In theory I could use Simpson rule but I don't know how to find the exact values of the shear force curve.

Normal I calculate its value at the end of every meter, and connect the dots.

Would someone help me by explaining the "proper" way to calculate it? The exam was a massacre, you'd help more than one student

Comment: Is there a difference between the fixed end and the end on a roller here? Are the loads all vertical, or do they also have a horizontal component? Is the roller there just to make sure there are no tensile forces?

Comment: Also, do you have the uneven distributed load as a function of the position along the girder?

Comment: No difference that I know of, I guess its to eliminate tensile forces though she never explained. All forces are 100% vertical. No the loads are given in value and postition of the beam (eg uneven distributed starts at 4m with 14kN and ends at 6.5m with 12kN)

Comment: Ok. So the load varies linearly with distance between those two points? Is the length of the girder given a value?

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember the exact question, though someone I know wrote it down. if you could solve the example as follows I'll try to solve the exam one: Length of beam 12m, point load at 2.5 meters of 12kN, even distributed load starts at 4meters and ends at 8meters with (begin/ending) force of 15kN. Uneven distributed load starts at 4 meters with 0 and ends at 8 meters with 4kN

Comment: Do you mean 0 kN/m and 4kN/m at the ends? Loads are forces per unit length

Comment: Yes, she only gives starting and ending value with postion, not the average force

Comment: Would [engineering.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are stuck on handling the non-uniform load distribution. I will just focus on this, then you can just add the contributions from the point and uniform distributions on top of this since you said you know how to handle these. I will be looking at what you have stated in the comments:

> Length of beam 12 m. Uneven distributed load starts at 4 meters with 0 kN/m and ends at 8 meters with 4 kN/m

Therefore, assuming the load varies linearly with distance between the specified end points, the distributed load is given by 
$$w(x)=(1\space \frac{kN}{m^2})x\space -\space (4 \space \frac{kN}{m})$$
when $4\space m<x<8\space m$, and is $0$ otherwise. Also, $x=0\space m$ corresponds to the left end of the beam, and increases to the right.

The first thing we need to do is determine the boundary conditions. This can be done by resolving the distributed load to a point load at the centroid of the distribution.

The total force is given by (dropping units on constants):
$$F_P=\int_0^L w(x)dx=\int_4^8(x-4)dx=8\space kN$$
which is just the "area" under the distributed load.

The location of this force is given by the centroid:
$$\bar x=\frac{\int_0^L xw(x)dx}{\int_0^L w(x)dx}=\frac{\int_4^8 (x^2-4x)dx}{8\space kN}=\frac {20}{3}\space m \approx 6.67 \space m$$

So we have resolved this distribution to a point force of $F_P=8\space kN$ at position $\bar x=6.67\space m$ from the left end of the beam. Next we need to determine the shear forces at the boundaries of our beam. This is where this point load we calculated comes into play, and it becomes a simple statics problem.

Let's call the force on the left end of the beam $F_L$. We must have no net torque about the right end of the beam, so $-F_L(12\space m)+F_P(12\space m - 6.67 \space m)=0$ Therefore, it must be that
$$F_L=\frac{(8 kN)(5.33 \space m)}{12\space m}\approx 3.56\space kN=-Q(0)$$

I have included the negative sign since the shear force will be negative at the left end of the beam.

We are done with the resolved point load and we need to consider the actual distributed load now. The shear force will be
$$Q(x)=\int_0^x w(x')dx'+Q(0)$$

This then means that for $x<4\space m$, 
$$Q(x)=Q(0)=-3.56\space kN$$

For $4\space m<x<8\space m$, we have
$$Q(x)=\int_4^x (x'-4)dx'-3.56\space kN=\left [\frac 12 (x-4)^2\right ] kN-3.56\space kN$$

And for $x>8\space m$ we have
$$Q(x)=\left [\frac 12 (8-4)^2\right ] kN-3.56\space kN=4.44 \space kN$$

Note: I have been a little sloppy in my inclusion of units in the above derivation, but if you are more careful with everything then it all works out.

Below is a graph of this function is below (the picture is not loading for now, but I will keep on trying). Also, we see that $3.56\space kN + 4.46\space kN=8 \space kN$ so that the net force on the beam is $0$ (which is what we want).

To get the bending moment, you can do what you explained in your question:
$$M(x)=\int_0^x Q(x')dx'$$
which is very similar to what we just walked through. As a check, we also find (if we don't round the numbers like I do above) that $M(0)=M(12)=0\space kN \cdot m$ , which is what we want due to the boundary conditions of the beam.

You can then take this along with your solutions of the point and uniform loads that you say you know how to do and add them all together, since the differential equations here are linear. Also notice that I put in the general formulas before applying them to the specific problem, so you should now be able to handle any type of non-uniform load, not just this triangular one. Let me know in the comments if you have any other questions.

Comment: Im trying to work it out, but I'm not there yet. for the w(x) equation the one because of its force divided by the length, and -4 because it starts there. But where does the triangle shape come in? For example, if L=2 and starting force is 50 at 0 and it ends with 30 at two meters, would the equation be 25x?

Comment: If you had a linearly varying load with 50 kN/m at 0 m and 30 kN/m at 2 m, then $w(x)=-(10\space kN/m)x+50\space kN/m$. This is just finding the equation of a line given two points on the line. If you were to graph this, it would have the shape of a trapezoid, if you counted the x-axis as one of the sides of the shape. I called your example in the problem a "triangle" because at one of the points the load was 0 kN/m, so the shape is a triangle.

Comment: Should've been obvious, thanks for pointing that out. I managed to complete the exercise, although I get the wrong sign. In the 2m exercise, shear force at 1m is |-5x²+50x| from 0 to 1 - 43.33 (centroid distance from Right side x total pointload (80kN)) it should however be -1.66... instead of +

Comment: If you do the same steps outlined above you should get the right answer. If your teacher/text uses different sign conventions then my process might be opposite signs of yours though. If you are getting all the right answers, but all of the signs are opposite, then that probably just means you used the opposite sign convention than the person who made the answers.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I got it! I'll make lots of exercises to be sure (thankfully there are calculators online so I check my self made exercises).

Comment: No problem. Make sure to mark this as the correct answer if it has sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: I'm able to solve all the questions with trapezium/triangle loads, as well as calculating their bending moment. How do you incorporate point loads into this? I can't put it in the equation because the limits of X, and altough the BM equation seems to work for all points (as you wrote, 0 to x) it no longer gives the right answer. Would you shed some light on this? I'm positive I'll manage after that

Comment: @LazarusJaeger Point loads give a discontinuous jump in the shear force at the point where the load is applied and is equal to the force of the load. For example, if you have 5 kN point load applied at 6 m, then going from x < 6 m to x > 6 m you would add 5 kN to Q(x). This will produce a "corner" in the graph of M(x), since it's derivative, Q(x), has a jump discontinuity.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if Q would be 5x² (3 to x) due to the trapezium it would become 5x² + 5 and  f(Q) 5x³/3 + 5x at 6 meters with the extra point load? Edit: yes it does. I'll toast to your health!